# Display contents of of an empty cell with "test" in excel using java

Tags: java, jxl

I get error from empty cell. I need to display all content from one column in an excel. Here is what I tried:

```
String Contents;
Contents = cell.getContents();

for(int j=1;j<=j+1;j++) {

    if (Contents != null && Contents.length() != 0) {
        Cell cell = sheet.getCell(i-1, j-1);
        CellType type = cell.getType();
        if (type == CellType.LABEL) {
            System.out.println("" + cell.getContents());
        }

        if (type == CellType.NUMBER) {
            System.out.println("" + cell.getContents());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What library are you using to communicate with Excel?

Comment: package reader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class ReadExcel {
..................................
  
Am using Java Jar files in netbean